# I have a transaction of 3 stored procedures : How can I use the output parameter from my former stored procedure to the current stored procedure?

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server

I have different input parameters to enter and all those parameters need to enter in different tables. Therefore I use 3 different stored procedures. From each stored procedure, i need to use the output parameter of the former stored procedure as an input parameter.

Those are the 3 stored procedures that I use

Stored procedure 1 = Levlotnr:

```
create procedure Levlotnr
     (@lotleverancier nvarchar (256), 
      @leverancier nvarchar (256), 
      @newinsertedlevID int output)
as
    insert into leveranciersLotnr
    values (@lotleverancier, 
            (select leveranciersID 
             from Leverancier 
             where LeveranciersNaam = @leverancier) )

    select @@IDENTITY as newinsertedlevID
```

Stored procedure 2 = LotIN:

```
create procedure LotIN
     (@datumIN datetime,
      @hoeveelIN decimal, 
      @grondstofIN nvarchar(256), 
      @newinsertedLotnrINID int output,
      @lotnlevID int)
as
    insert into LotnummerIN
    values (@datumIN, @hoeveelIN, 
            (select GrondstofID 
             from Grondstoffen 
             where Grondstofomschrijving = @grondstofIN), 
            @lotnlevID)

    select @@IDENTITY as newinsertedLotnrIN
```

Stored procedure 3 = StockIN:

```
create procedure StockIN
    (@omschrstockIN nvarchar (256), 
     @lotnrIN int)
as 
     update StockPlaatsIN
     set LotnummerINID = @lotnrIN
     where StockINOmschrijving = @omschrstockIN
```

And this is a code that I already wrote

```
public void Nieuweontvangst (DateTime datumIN, string leverancier, 
                             string levlotnr, double hoeveelheidIN, 
                             string eenheidIN, string grondstofIN, 
                             string stockplaatsIN, int lotnrlevID, int lotnrINID)
{
       var manager = new LotnummersDBManager();

       using (var conLotnummers = manager.Getconnection())
       {
            conLotnummers.Open();

            using (var traNieuweOntvangst = 
conLotnummers.BeginTransaction(IsolationLevel.ReadCommitted))
            {//begin traNieuweOntvangst
                //first transaction: the output parameter @newinsertedlevID 
//just needs to be used in the second transaction, but not be displayed
                //------------------
                using (var comlevlotnrs = conLotnummers.CreateCommand())
                {
                    comlevlotnrs.Transaction = traNieuweOntvangst;
                    comlevlotnrs.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                    comlevlotnrs.CommandText = "Levlotnr"; //name of first 
                        stored procedure

                    var parlotleverancier = comlevlotnrs.CreateParameter();
                    parlotleverancier.ParameterName = "@Lotleverancier";
                    parlotleverancier.Value = levlotnr;
                    comlevlotnrs.Parameters.Add(parlotleverancier);

                    var parleverancier = comlevlotnrs.CreateParameter();
                    parleverancier.ParameterName = "@leverancier";
                    parleverancier.Value = leverancier;
                    comlevlotnrs.Parameters.Add(parleverancier);

                    var parlotlevID = comlevlotnrs.CreateParameter();
                    parlotlevID.ParameterName = "@newinsertedlevID";
                    parlotlevID.DbType = DbType.Int32;
                    parlotlevID.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
                    comlevlotnrs.Parameters.Add(parlotlevID);
                    }

                using (var comLotnrsIN = conLotnummers.CreateCommand())
                {// second transaction= output parameter @newinsertedlevID 
                 // should be used here where now stands @lotnrlevIN. 
                 // THIS IS WHERE I STRUGGLE
                 // also here I get an output parameter 
                 // @newinsertedLotnrINID only to be used in the 3rd 
                 // transaction, not to be displayed.

                    comLotnrsIN.Transaction = traNieuweOntvangst;
                    comLotnrsIN.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                    comLotnrsIN.CommandText = "LotnrIN";

                    var pardatumIN = comLotnrsIN.CreateParameter();
                    pardatumIN.ParameterName = "@datumIN";
                    pardatumIN.Value = datumIN;
                    comLotnrsIN.Parameters.Add(pardatumIN);

                    var parhoeveelIN = comLotnrsIN.CreateParameter();
                    parhoeveelIN.ParameterName = "@hoeveelIN";
                    parhoeveelIN.Value = hoeveelheidIN;
                    comLotnrsIN.Parameters.Add(parhoeveelIN);

                    var pargrondstofIN = comLotnrsIN.CreateParameter();
                    pargrondstofIN.ParameterName = "@grondstofIN";
                    pargrondstofIN.Value = grondstofIN;
                    comLotnrsIN.Parameters.Add(pargrondstofIN);

                    var parlotnrlevIN = comLotnrsIN.CreateParameter();
                    parlotnrlevIN.ParameterName = "@lotnrlevIN";
                    parlotnrlevIN.Value = lotnrlevID;
                    comLotnrsIN.Parameters.Add(parlotnrlevIN);

                    var parLotIN = comLotnrsIN.CreateParameter();
                    parLotIN.ParameterName = "@newinsertedLotnrINID";
                    parLotIN.DbType = DbType.Int32;
                    parLotIN.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
                    comLotnrsIN.Parameters.Add(parLotIN);
                }

                using (var comStockeren = conLotnummers.CreateCommand())
                {
                 //Third transaction
                 // I need to use the output parameter from 2nd transaction 
                 // @newinsertedLotnrINID where you see now @lotnrINID. 
                 //THIS IS THE SAME STRUGGLE AS 2ND TRANSACTION

                    comStockeren.Transaction = traNieuweOntvangst;
                    comStockeren.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                    comStockeren.CommandText = "StockIN";

                    var parlotIN = comStockeren.CreateParameter();
                    parlotIN.ParameterName = "@lotnrINID";
                    parlotIN.Value = lotnrINID;

                    var paromschrStockIN = comStockeren.CreateParameter();
                    paromschrStockIN.ParameterName = "@omschrstockIN";
                    paromschrStockIN.Value = stockplaatsIN;
                    comStockeren.Parameters.Add(paromschrStockIN);
                }
                traNieuweOntvangst.Commit();
            } 
        }
    }
```

Comment: I would recommend to use **`SCOPE_IDENTITY()`** instead of anything (like `@@identity`) else to grab the newly inserted identity value. [See this blog post for an explanation as to WHY](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/03/25/sql-server-identity-vs-scope_identity-vs-ident_current-retrieve-last-inserted-identity-of-record/)

Comment: Also: using `decimal` as your data type on one of the parameters for your second stored procedure is equivalent to `decimal(18,0)` - which means: **no digits** after the decimal point! Is that really what you wanted?!?!?!? If not, you must **explicitly** specify the precision and scale - like `decimal(16,4)` to get a total of 16 digits, 4 of them after the decimal point ...

Comment: Ideally it should be 1 stored procedure for the whole transaction. Try using scope_identity() as mentioned by marc_s and combine into single proc

Comment: Hi @marc_s, I noticed indeed that I did not specify the number of digits after the decimal point. I will try to go on with scope_identity now and see what happens.

Comment: thanks for both tips and trics, I'm one step further now.